# Перекрытие элементов position: absolute;

Tags: html, css

Расположил картинку через

```
position: absolute;
```

а она перекрыла ссылку и, соответственно, ссылка не работает. Что делать?

Comment: Добавьте пример своего кода и расскажите как это должно работать

Comment: Без вашего кода вам никто не поможет

Answer (score 3):

Если в одном месте страницы оказываются несколько «абсолютных» блоков, то они перекрывают друг друга. По умолчанию выше оказывается тот блок, который расположен дальше в коде страницы.

C помощью CSS-свойства z-index можно управлять тем, как перекрываются блоки. Значением этого свойства может быть целое число. Чем больше z-index, тем выше располагается блок.

Cвойство z-index работает для элементов, у которых position задано как absolute, fixed и relative. **Таким образом, «относительный» элемент может перекрывать «абсолютный».**

Comment: не совсем так. я понял о чем вы говорите, но у меня проблема другая. есть меню сайта и элемент (картинка) настолько большая , что когда ее позиционируешь через абсолют , она перекрывает часть ссылки.